# fluentd full buffer cannot send log to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kubernetes, fluentd, okd

I find issue, where my fluentd full buffer and cannot send log to elastic. is there a way to manually flush?

this is error log

[image]

Comment: Could you please paste the error message as a text?

Answer (score 1):

Arghya's suggestion is correct but there are more options that can help you.

1. You can set `flush_mode` to `immediate` in order to force flush or set or set additional flush parameters in order to adjust it to your needs. You can read more about it here: [Control Flushing](https://docs.fluentd.org/output#control-flushing).
2. You can also consider using [SIGUSR1 Signal](https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/signals#sigusr1):

> Forces the buffered messages to be flushed and reopens Fluentd's log.
>   Fluentd will try to flush the current buffer (both memory and file)
>   immediately, and keep flushing at `flush_interval`.

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Increase flush_thread_count parameter

```
<match test>
  @type output_plugin
  <buffer ...>
    flush_thread_count 8
    ...
  </buffer>
  ...
</match>
```